# Qt refreshes at 60 FPS and eats GPU

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application that starts refreshing at 60FPS, but I can't detect why.

I used QML profiler and I can't see any event that triggers redraw. 
Using:

```
QSG_RENDERER_DEBUG=debug
QSG_RENDER_TIMING=1
```

I see

> Gui Thread: window=0x7fffffffe400, polish=0, lock=0, block/sync=15 --
>   animations=0

written very often. The message starts to appear at this rate after few seconds from startup without doing any actions. The timing seems to be random - sometimes is starts after 5 seconds, sometimes after 15 seconds.

Using:

```
QSG_VISUALIZE=changes
```

I see the entire screen being refreshed - the application is full screen.

I'm using Qt 5.3 on Linux Debian 8, Kernel 4.91. This eats about 25% of my NVIDIA 980. On Debian 8, Kernel 3.16 it eats more than 50% of Intel integrated GPU.

Do you have any hints on how may I detect what is triggering  the refresh?

Comment: Strip down your application until you localise the code which generates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stripping down the application I've got to an old C++ class who had this:

```
::paint()
{
    ...
    update();
    ...
}
```

This created an infinite `paint<->update` loop which didn't triggered stackoverflow just because they run in different threads:)

The apparent randomness came from the fact that the C++ object was used in multiple places from the QML code.

I don't know if this is relevant for the original question as it's a classic programming error, unrelated with Qt framework.

Comment: `This created an infinite paint<->update loop which didn't triggered stackoverflow just because they run in different threads:)` Actually they run in the same, but the update event is queued through the O.S. event loop. So its more like a `while` than a recursive loop.